# Saving Specific line of richTextBox in a Variable C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Using this code i get the line of characters which I want to store in a variable

```
string find = textBox1.Text;
string lineText = null;
int lineNum = richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(richTextBox1.Find(find));
MessageBox.Show("Line Number is " + lineNum);
```

How can I store the resulted line text from richTextBox in string variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Lines[] array:

```
int charNum = richTextBox1.Find(find);
if (charNum > -1) {
  lineText = richTextBox1.Lines[richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(charNum)];
}
```

Comment: Can you help me find next match for example i have date 2013 in richtextbox twice this code get first occurrence of 2013 I also want to find next date and its line text.  @Lars Tech

Comment: @Hanni The Find() function has a second optional parameter of where to start looking.

Comment: Can you provide me example please. @Lars Tech

Comment: @Hanni Something like `charNum = rtb.Find(find, charNum + 1, RichTextBoxFinds.None);`  Please try researching this kind of thing first.  You just have to look at the notes for the [Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.find(v=vs.110).aspx) method.